# Git - how to backtrack lost version of a file

Tags: git, merge, corruption

I have recently hit by a weird scenario in Git.
There is a file `a.x` that was initially checked in the Git. After few days, there were some modifications done in that file, creating version 2 of that file. Now, after quite a few commits in the master branch, I see the history of this file and I just see the initial version of that file. I was expecting that the content of the file could be exactly as version 1, (if somebody has done a bad merge or something of that sort) but the history should show three versions of that file.  Can someone please help to understand as whether this is a case of corruption in repository or the bad merges can take away the history of the file as well?

```
---  a.x - Version 1 
-----a.x - version 2, version 1
----after some commits
-----a.x - version 1 ( just showing version 1 - no sign of version 2)
```

Comment: history of the file? Does a commit that contains the changes of version 2 exist in the log tree?

Comment: Well, clearly a commit reversed the modifications to the file, bringing it back to the same content as it had originally. This is neither uncommon nor strange. What may be strange/odd is that someone did this in your repository, but from gits viewpoint there is nothing odd about it. I am assuming that if you checkout the commit bringing the file up to "version 2", it still has that content?

Comment: What tool are you using to view the history of the file? Are you using the command line or some GUI tool? What is the list at the end of your question? Is this the output from some command?

Comment: Hi, My issue is that the history of that file is not showing 2 (or more versions). The history is just showing 1 version. I am using Altasian stash server. I see the file history using command line in my local system as well. For this file, it is showing only one version. Even by wrong merge, if the content of the file is reverted to the original, still it should be listed as another version of the file.